Simple insurance model in R
During my course in R I was given a task to create insurance model with variables (T=months, K=insurance premium, N=number of customers, F=payout in case event happens).
My role is to create reserve for payments (S1<-KN in period 1, S2<-S1+KN in period 2 etc), to create a payout model which will happen until solvency is sustained.
Do you know how to program it?
For the time being I did:
N<-20000 #number of customers
K<-200 #monthly insurance premium
F<-30000 #payout amount (in case met)
T<-30   #number of months
probability<-0.03 # 3% possibility in a year

#1.first year
t<-1
#full amount
for (t in 1:T) {
    W <-K*N*T } 

print(paste0("Full insurance paid", W))

#2. Reserve for payout with particular probability
Reserve=probability/12*T*N*F

#3. payout probability (monthly)
PP=(F*N*probability)/12 

How to correctly simulate if business is still solvent?
Maybe I need to introduce some random numbers to modify constant/defined numbers?
Thank you in advance for help!

Hi, Mike_R. This forum is really meant for pretty specific coding questions, like "I am trying to do blah blah blah, and I tried X but I got an error..." Your question is just too open ended for Stack Overflow. Good luck to you.
